# how to calculate parent dict value based on child value in nested dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have python nested dictionary with unfixed order and update the parent count and size value based on child count and size value. But both values are available in last nested dict.

Input Dict-

```
[{'name': 'stack', 'children': 
    [{'name': 'flow', 'children': 
        [{'name': 'lldp', 'children':
            [{'name': 'sourc', 'children': 
                [{'name': 'lldque.jrc', 'count': '11', 'size': '37'}]}]}, 
         {'name': 'arp', 'children': 
            [{'name': 'src', 'children': 
                [{'name': 'arpred.cec', 'count': '37', 'size': '67'}]}]}]}]}]
```

Output Dict should be as below-

```
[{'name':'stack','count':'4','size':'6','children':
    [{'name':'flow','count':'4','size':'6','children':
        [{'name':'lldp','count':'1','size':'2','children':
            [{'name':'sourc','count':'1','size':'2','children':
                [{'name':'lldque.jrc','count':'1','size':'2'}]}]},
         {'name':'arp','count':'3','size':'4','children':
            [{'name':'src','count':'3','size':'4','children':
                [{'name':'arpred.cec','count':'3','size':'4'}]}]}]}]}]
```

currently I am using below code;

```
def populateParentDict(ddict):
    listl = []
    if type(ddict) == list:
        if 'children' in ddict[0]:
            return populateParentDict(ddict[0])
        else:
            listl.append(ddict[0]['Buggy'])
            listl.append(ddict[0]['Clean'])
    elif 'children' in ddict:
        return populateParentDict(ddict['children'])
    return listl
```

Comment: Your input and output dicts are lists, is that intentional?

Comment: Not entirely sure where numbers `3` and `4` come from in your output example.

Comment: Even after formatting the dicts, I'm with Yakym: I have no idea how you expect these numbers to be transformed.

Comment: Input and output values are in JSON format. In input value each level are separated by list and dict, Parent dict contain two keys (name and children). In last child value contain three key(name, count, size). I have to update and add two new key in each parent(count and size). If one parent has multiple children with count and size then I have to calculate all child values and update to the parent.